# Setup project visual studio 2010 with QT and open cv

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

did anyone know how to make a project setup ?
im using qt open cv with  visual studio 2010 
my project run fine in pc without any problem.

i need to create a file setup to run my project  in other platform

how can i  make this setup with all necessary dll  ?

PS : i have make a setup file and i have install it in other pc

after installation and when I run the application, it crashes

So I think the steps that I have followed are false

please help

Comment: You can use dependency walker to see which dll's are missing and find out why.

Comment: Canberk thanks for the answer, i have make a build for my project in the release mode and then i have copy this folder and execute the project.exe there and that works fine in the other machine .but the problem when i make in the setup project all the dll that are present in the realease mode,after that i install it the application crashes !

Comment: Then you already know what dlls you need. Check on the other machine what dlls arent installed using http://www.dependencywalker.com/. If you cannot find out whats missing, use a third party software, not Visual Studio to create the setup http://www.sminstall.com/ -because you already know all the dlls needed.